# Convert complex string(contains objects) to JSON Object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a string which is made on run-time depends on user inputs. When user enters some searching criteria the string is creating based on that input and the string is actually an complex objects. When i am trying to `JSON.parse()` and pass it to the mongoDB find() method to find data in a database and that gives me an error and that is fine. But my object are not a simple key-values pairs actually my objects are key and values are other object to in this case ithink the `JSON.parse()` method is failing to convert it to a actual JSON Object. I tried some custom implementations as well but i failed alot...

**Dynamically Created String**

`"{ "name": { $regex: name, $options: "i" },
"code": { $regex: code, $options: "i" },
"phoneNumber": { $regex: phone, $options: "i" },
"nic": { $regex: cnic, $options: "i"  }"`

When i try to `JSON.parse()` it i am getting an error UNEXPECTED token error at position $....

**Error Image**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qIlh.jpg)

Help will be appreciated... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON all names of objects and their properties must be enclosed in `"` double-quote characters. Your string has names like `$regex` and `$options` without the double-quote characters. Put in those characters and you should be good to go.

Comment: i tried this but agian in am getting in error...i am posted image to my question.

Comment: You need another `}` at the end of your JSON string. Balance your curly braces.